# jQuery: Clicking button doesn't trigger event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ejs

I am trying to change the row of the table according to the button clicked. The row changes for the first time button is clicked, but after that row value doesn't change. Also, the event listner is removed after button changes.

[image: Link]

HTML:

```
<% if(post.status === 1){ %>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Disapprove"    id="disapproveBtn-<%= i %>">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send to Moderation" id="moderateBtn-<%= i %>">
<% } %>
```

jQuery:

```
$("[id|='disapproveBtn']").click(function (e) {
  console.log("CLICKED");
  var trIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var postId = $(this).closest('tr').find("#postId").text().trim();
  $.post('/admin/disapprove/' + postId, (data) => {
    console.log(tr);


    console.log(data);
    tr.html(`
      <td>
        ${data.post.firstName}
      </td>

      <td>
        ${data.post.lastName}
      </td>

      <td>
        ${data.post.userId}
      </td>

      <td>
        <div id="postId">
          ${data.post.id}
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="/profile/post/${data.post.id}">Here</a>
      </td>

      <td>
        ${data.post.status}
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Approve" id="approveBtn-${trIndex}">
        <input type="button" value="Send to Moderation" class="btn btn-primary" id="moderateBtn-${trIndex}">
      </td>
    `)
  });
});
```

Comment: guessing it is dynamic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Could you not avoid the problem entirely by just using a class selector?

Comment: **What do you espect? You replace the whole table row, including the buttons. The replaced buttons of course don't have an event listener attached.**

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Still it changes the html for first time dissaprove button is clicked. When approve button is clicked, nothing happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Use [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/): `$("some-static-container-selector").on("click","[id|='disapproveBtn']",function (e) {`

Answer (score 0):

Due to reputation I can't make this a comment it looks like you have a dynamic id

```
disapproveBtn-<%= i %>
```

Your event listener is looking at disapproveBtn not each individual one

```
<% if(post.status === 1){ %>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger disapproveButton" value="Disapprove"    id="disapproveBtn-<%= i %>">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send to Moderation" id="moderateBtn-<%= i %>">
```

and then alter your event listener to be
$(".disapproveButton").click(function (e) {

Comment: OP is using the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/), and it's not dynamic so it should work fine.

Comment: So he is, my mistake

Comment: $("[id|='disapproveBtn']")
This selects everything starting with disapproveBtn-

Comment: @AshishSubedi - read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0):

I want to be clear on what you're expecting:

1. The user clicks the `disapprove` button inside a table row
2. The row changes, and should now contain an `approve` button
3. The user clicks the `approve` button, and something happens

The reason nothing happens when they click the `approve` button is that all your event listeners are created **when the page first loads**. The `approve` button is created *after* the page loads, and so it does not have an event listener.

I would recommend that you always have an 'approve' button in each row when the page loads, but just hide it with CSS (`display:none`) until the `disapprove` button has been clicked.

Otherwise, you will need to set an event listener on each `approve` button when it is created.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am expecting. Thanks, I am going to try that.

Comment: Let me know what happens!